# сдвиг вправо с присваиванием в c#

Tags: java, c#

В java есть оператор >>= - сдвиг вправо с присваиванием.

```
if ($num >>= 7) {

}
```

Как будет в c# аналог этого оператора?*

Comment: Что значит $ в java?

Comment: Ну >>= и в C# работает. Непонятно только, как вы это в `if` засунули

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по синтаксису - вы говорите вовсе не Java, а о JavaScript. Там - да, написанное вами условие сработает.

В C# и Java, если не переопределять соответствующий оператор, то аналогичное условие выглядит как:

```
((num >>= 7) != 0)
```